# How to check if a value is in a document's field (which is an array)

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

Say we have a collection `users`:

```json
{
    "name" : "Doe",
    "books": ["b1", "b2"]
},
{
    "name" : "Jhon",
    "books": ["b1", "b3"]
}
```

I want to check if a book `b3` is in this collection (doesn't matter which document/`user`). How can I achieve that?

Comment: It seems it is the most basic use case of [find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)? Is there any specific difficulty you faced?

Answer (score 0):

Following query will get you the user who had "b3" book:

```
users.find( { books: ["b3"] } )
```

for further study:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/